# Read and use JSON data from file in File Directory

Tags: javascript, json, file, parsing

I am trying to access some / all the data from the **xmltojson.json** file. Does anyone know how to assign the data to an variable, using javascript?

```
const jsonfile = require('jsonfile')
const file = 'xmltojson.json'
jsonfile.readFile(file, function (err, obj) {
  if (err) console.error(err)
  console.dir(obj)
})
```

[image]

Comment: Do you already have some code to share?

Comment: I've added some code but get the following error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at script.js:1

Answer (score 0):

Here are tow methods to solve this questions.

1. NodeJS

1.1 If you use read method in Node and determined to needn't any packages or budle or module in this file, you can use it:

```
const fileContext = JsonFileName.readFileAsync(file);
const jsonContext = Jason.parse(fileContext)
```

1.2 use require.

```
const file = require('fileName.json')
```

**Caution:**

- require can't dynamic change content when json file changed.
- require just support files' suffix is json, like '*.json'.

2. If you write this code in webpack, just import

   import './fileName.json'

Comment: determined to needn't lol

Comment: I forget how to use English, lol

Answer (score 0):

You can just import your .json file with

```
import jsondata from './xmltojson.json'
```

in your *script.js* file.

Then, If you want to reach the **ItemStartDate** data, you can use dot notation with indexes as usual:

```
const itemstartdate = jsondata.MBS_XML.Data[0].ItemStartDate;
```